# How to merge data in DataFrame in overlapping time periods in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
           start_time status               duration
0 2023-03-16 01:30:00     OK        0 days 00:02:00          
1 2023-03-16 01:31:00   WARN        0 days 00:19:28  
2 2023-03-16 01:31:00  ERROR        0 days 00:09:28  
3 2023-03-16 01:32:00  ERROR        0 days 00:03:00
4 2023-03-16 01:33:00     OK        0 days 00:03:00
5 2023-03-16 01:35:00     OK        0 days 12:05:28
```

It has a list of `status`, and for how long each `status` lasts, the time periods could be overlapped.

I need to merge the time periods and get the worst `status` when they overlap to form a new time frame, which should look like:

```
           start_time status        
0 2023-03-16 01:30:00     OK                
1 2023-03-16 01:31:00  ERROR
2 2023-03-16 01:40:28   WARN
3 2023-03-16 01:50:28     OK
```

It started with OK status, the next period in WARN overlapped with ERROR so we keep the ERROR, and when the period in ERROR finished change back to WARN, and then back to OK. Rows 3 4 are skipped due to overlapped with ERROR in row 2.

The idea I have is for each row in the data frame, calculate an `end_time` based on `start_time + duration`, use the `start_time` and `end_time` to create a time series with 10s timedelta, explode the time series to a data frame and fill forward with `status`, then align or `merge_asof` the dataframes pairwise and create a function to aggregate the status by worst case... sounds very inefficient and slow, it has 100k data rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I calculate the `end_times`. Then I collect all the times (except the last time, since that's the final `end_time`) and map the most important event to that time and store that as a `events`. Then, I remove duplicate consecutive rows by comparing it to itself shifted by one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start_time": [
            "2023-03-16 01:30:00",
            "2023-03-16 01:31:00",
            "2023-03-16 01:31:00",
            "2023-03-16 01:32:00",
            "2023-03-16 01:33:00",
            "2023-03-16 01:35:00",
        ],
        "status": ["OK", "WARN", "ERROR", "ERROR", "OK", "OK"],
        "duration": [
            "00:02:00",
            "00:19:28",
            "00:09:28",
            "00:03:03",
            "00:03:00",
            "12:05:28",
        ],
    }
)
df["start_time"] = df["start_time"].astype("datetime64")
df["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"])

df["end_time"] = df["start_time"] + df["duration"]

priority = {"ERROR": 0, "WARN": 1, "OK": 2}

times = np.union1d(df["start_time"], df["end_time"])

events = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        time: min(
            df.loc[(df.start_time <= time) & (df.end_time > time), "status"].values,
            key=lambda x: priority[x],
        )
        for time in times[:-1]
    },
    "index",
)

display(events)

events = events[events[0] != events[0].shift()]

display(events)
```

Output:

```
                    0
2023-03-16 01:30:00 OK
2023-03-16 01:31:00 ERROR
2023-03-16 01:40:28 WARN
2023-03-16 01:50:28 OK
```

Comment: If OP wants the exact output format shown in the question, add this line: `events = events.reset_index().set_axis(["start_time", "status"], axis=1)`

Comment: There is one minor problem, that when the worst status changed from `ERROR` back to `OK`, it will undercount OK at that time. I think one way to workaround is set the `end_time` to be slightly before the next `start_time`, like 1 millisecond before

Comment: I thought I fixed that when I changed the comparison from `df.end_time >= time` to `>`. This should prevent the end of an event from being counted as being active at that time.

Comment: ah yes indeed, I was thinking about a slightly different scenario. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': ['2023-03-16 01:30:00 ', '2023-03-16 01:31:00', '2023-03-16 01:31:00', 
                                  '2023-03-16 01:32:00', '2023-03-16 01:33:00', '2023-03-16 01:35:00'], 
                   'status': ["OK", "WARN", "ERROR", "ERROR", "OK", "OK"], 
                   'duration': ["0 days 00:02:00", "0 days 00:19:28", "0 days 00:09:28", 
                                "0 days 00:03:00", "0 days 00:03:00", "0 days 12:05:28"], 
                   })

df['diff'] = ( pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']) + pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']) ).diff()

def reduce(g):
    d = {False:g, True:g.iloc[:-1,:]}[len(g)>1]
    mask = d['diff'].gt(datetime.timedelta(0)) 
    
    if len(g)>1:
        return pd.concat([d.loc[d['diff'][mask].index], d.tail(1)], axis=0)
    else:
        return d
        
r = (df.groupby('status')
       .apply(lambda g: reduce(g))
       .reset_index(allow_duplicates=True)
       .T
       .drop_duplicates(keep='first')
       .T
       .drop('diff',axis=1)
       )

r['start_time'] = ( pd.to_timedelta(r['duration']) + pd.to_datetime(r['start_time']) )

print(r[['start_time', 'status']])
```

**Result**

```
           start_time status
0 2023-03-16 01:40:28  ERROR
1 2023-03-16 01:36:00     OK
2 2023-03-16 01:36:00     OK
3 2023-03-16 01:50:28   WARN
```